# I'm getting undefined when returning the array from the function, although the array changed

Tags: javascript

I have a function that's supposed to use recursion, and return an array of numbers from startNum to endNum, although I successfully got an array with the numbers I'm looking for the function is returning undefined.

```js
let arr = []

function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if(startNum == endNum){
      arr.push(startNum)
      return arr;
  } else {
      arr.push(startNum)
      startNum++;
      rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum);
  }
};

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(6, 9))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Every path has to return something. Only one of two paths does this in your example.

Comment: You should define your array inside of `rangeOfNumbers` and build on that recursively, otherwise you will have issues if you call your function more than once ([examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66406282/5648954))

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not returning the recursion, just add a return

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if(startNum == endNum){
      arr.push(startNum)
      return arr;
  } else {
      arr.push(startNum)
      startNum++;
      return rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum);
  }
};
```